# Sass compilation error with classes

Tags: css, web, compilation, sass

```
.profile-img{
    border-radius: 8px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 5px solid green;
}
```

This is standard css but for some reason I am getting the following error when I try to compile it:

Error: Invalid CSS after "8px": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";"
        on line 2 of C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Web Design\Practice_profile.sass
  Use --trace for backtrace.
[Finished in 0.4s]

Answer (score 0):

It works well with me bro !
I think that's a problem with your compiler. 
I'm using Gulp 

This is my gulpfile.js
You can install Gulp and Gulp-sass
Use CMD go to your folder contains gulpfile then run : gulp watch
Everytime you change your scss file it will compile css file for you

```
* file: gulpfile.js */

var gulp   = require('gulp'),
    sass   = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('build-css', function() {
  return gulp.src('css/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});

/* updated watch task to include sass */
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(['css/*.scss'], ['build-css']);
});
```